# Google AdMob error in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, admob

I've integrated **AdMob** in my iOS project but it gives me the following error.

> module 'GoogleMobileAds' not found

I have already imported the AdMob SDK into my project and added the following import.

```
@import GoogleMobileAds;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Build Settings of you project set the **Define Modules** to **YES**. Then, remove the AdMob Framework from your project, clean your project, and import the AdMob Framework again.

Answer (score 0):

Change the import calls:

`@import GoogleMobileAds`

to this

`#import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>`